# Hot keys with tab control on child form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I am working on a Winform application in C#. I have a from frmPlan.frm and on that form I have some buttons/textboxes and a panel control. When that form load we load another form frmPlanDetail.frm inside that panel.

Now on that frmPlanDetail form we have a tab control and I was trying to implement hotkeys to navigate between tabs. I was able to implement the hotkeys by overriding the ProcessCmdKey event in frmPlanDetail.frm. But the problem that I am facing is it does not work untill I click on that tab control first. Once I click that control to set the focus it works after that but not after I load the form initially because at that time focus is on frmPlam form. I am using the following code for hot keys

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
   if (keyData == (Keys.Alt  | Keys.P))
   {
      tabCtrlIPE.SelectedIndex = 3;
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle hot keys is to add a MenuStrip, add a MenuItem and assign it your hot key (Alt + P in your case) and make the Visibility of the MenuItem as false. Now wire-up the menu item click event to do what you wanted to do.

Eventhough the menu is invisible, it would trigger the click event on pressing the hotkey.

I consider this as a straight-forward way for implementing hot keys as you don't have to deal with the control on which to handle key-press event, and adding your if-else ladders or switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

It works OK for me when you place the code in the *Top level parent* (the outermost form):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
  }
  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt  | Keys.P)) {
       tabCtrlIPE.SelectedIndex = 3;
       return true;//Prevent beep sound
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
  }
}
```